# ¿Como modificar el tamaño de una columna en Angular con PrimeNG?

Tags: angular, primeng

me pueden ayudar como puedo modificar el tamaño de las columnas en Angular para lo cual ocupo PrimeNG.
La tabla que tengo llama los datos guardados en la BD, para lo cual llamamos desde el .ts pero según el código que tengo el tamaño esta muy ancho el ID.

[image: Imagen de referencia]

HTML

```
    <p-table #dt [columns]="columnas" [value]="preguntas" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="preguntaSeleccionada" (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" [paginator]="true" [rows]="15">
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <h3> Lista de Preguntas </h3>
        <div style="text-align: left">
          <i class="fa fa-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
          <input type="text" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Filtro Global" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto"></div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
          <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
            {{rowData[col.field]}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
        <div style="text-align:left">
          <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-plus" routerLink="../agregarPregunta" class="ui-button-rounded" style="margin-left: 10px" role="button" routerLinkActive="active" label="Nueva pregunta"></button>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

La parte del .TS

```
    constructor(private servicePre: PreguntasService, private router: Router) { }`
    ngOnInit() {
    this.listar();
    this.columnas = [
      { field: 'preguntas_Id', header: 'Id', size: '11' },
      { field: 'preguntas_Descripcion', header: 'Descripcion' },
      { field: 'preguntas_Estado', header: 'Estado' },
    ];
  `}`
 `listar() {
    this.servicePre.getPregunta().subscribe(data => {
      this.preguntas = data;
    });
  }`
```

Comment: Hola. No se te entiende muy bien cual es el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [width]/witdh, depende si quieres que el tamaño se ha dinamico. Tanto el header como el body deben tener el mismo tamaño.

```
  <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" [width]="col.width">
        {{col.header}}
        <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field" ariaLabel="Activate to sort" ariaLabelDesc="Activate to sort in descending order" ariaLabelAsc="Activate to sort in ascending order"></p-sortIcon>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [width]="col.width">
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
```